# site heart uncaught exception

Tags: php, smarty

Hello all trying to install siteheart live chat by using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   _shcp = [];
   _shcp.push({widget_id : 613530, widget : "Chat", side : "top", position : "left" }); 

   (function(){
      var hcc = document.createElement("script");
      hcc.type = "text/javascript";
      hcc.async = true;
      hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http") + "://widget.siteheart.com/apps/js/sh.js";
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
   })();
</script>
```

But getting next error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "

What is it and why am I seeing this?

Comment: Is that because I am using local machine?

Comment: The error is syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using smarty on your page. I think the error is related to the curly brackets on your javascript it is interfering with smarty syntax.

Try to put your script inside a literal smarty block

```js
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript"> _shcp = []; _shcp.push({widget_id : 613530, widget : "Chat", side : "top", position : "left" }); (function() { var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true; hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://widget.siteheart.com/apps/js/sh.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling); })(); </script>
{/literal}
```